# How to instruct Eclipse to record relative paths of the external jars?

Tags: eclipse

Here is my .classpath file, after I have added two more external jars (org.restlet.ext.simple.jar and org.simpleframework.jar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar" sourcepath="C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/docs/ext/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.restlet.ext.ssl.jar" sourcepath="C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/docs/ext/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.restlet.jar" sourcepath="C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/docs/api"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.jsslutils_1.0/org.jsslutils.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.codehaus.jackson_1.4/org.codehaus.jackson.core.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.codehaus.jackson_1.4/org.codehaus.jackson.mapper.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/guice-3.0/aopalliance.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/guice-3.0/guice-3.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/guice-3.0/javax.inject.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/dev/poc/3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.restlet.ext.simple.jar" sourcepath="C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Program Files/Java/restlet-jse-2.0.10/docs/ext/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/dev/poc/3rd_party/restlet-jse-2.0.10/lib/org.simpleframework_4.1/org.simpleframework.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Notice that they have been added with absolute paths, unlike other entries which are with relative ones, but only because I manually edit this file each time new external jars are added.

My question is can I somehow tell Eclipse to use relative paths of newly added external jars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One solution is to not use external jars, but to put your jars into a project, and then use Add Jar(s) instead of Add External Jar(s).

This makes sense from the point of view of source control, you can add/remove dependencies as you need them. It also means that when you update one jar for a separate project, it'll not affect this one.

We've done this in the past, we had a single project which contained all of the jars, which were referred to in the build paths of other projects.

But now we use maven, so we don't need to do that any more.

Comment: What was the kind of that project? Just a Java Project or anything else?

Comment: Just a java project, IIRC. Just added a lib dir and put the jars in.

Comment: Could explain the process in more detail, because I am trying to retrace your steps and I still do not see any jars in the "Add Jars" dialog.

Comment: But then how did you know which jars are the dependencies of the particular project?

Comment: Ok, so my project is called foobar. I create a folder in the project called lib. Externally to Eclipse, I copy a jar (bar.jar) into that library, and then in Eclipse I refresh the project. Then, in the build path of one of the other projects, I select Java Build Path, Libraries tab. I click on Add JARs, and select the foobar project, and drill down and select lib/bar.jar. Save. Then I have an entry like classpathentry kind="lib" path="/foobar/lib/xercesImpl-1.5.jar" in my .classpath.

Comment: very helpful, I was looking for this.

Comment: NOTE: this will not work if the jar you are referencing contains a manifest with relative references to other jars. In this case you must use an absolute path. too bad. would really like to have an option to ref these kind of jars relatively...

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse, right-click the project, choose **Properties**, then **Java Build Path**, **Libraries** tab and select "**Add Jars**"... this will add it with **a relative path**. "**Add External JARs**" adds the jar with **an absolute path** which is not what you want.

Comment: I have no jars to select there.

Comment: OK, but what if your jars aren't in the folder where your project is?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Eclipse relative paths should **begin with a single dot**.

Instead of

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="../3rd_party/example.jar"/>
```

You need to use

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="./../3rd_party/example.jar"/>
```

The first method might sometimes work, but the second method works always.

This is very confusing because you might have 5 entries in classpath that work with the ".." at the beginning and the others won't work with it.

Change all references to begin with the single dot first.

Answer (score 1):

If your paths are relative to your Eclipse installation, declare them using the “Add Variable…” button (in [Project] → Properties → Java Build Path → Libraries). There you should be offered a variable called `ECLIPSE_HOME`, which you can then *Extend*. This will produce a „kind=var“ entry in your `.classpath`(rather than a „kind=lib“).

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="ECLIPSE_HOME/...
```

If your paths are relative to somewhere else you can declare your own variables (*Configure variables*). This way, when your workspace changes or someone makes a copy of it you just need to update these variables. This is often clearer than having true relative paths starting with one or two dots.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostic ("Matthew Farwell" may have the only workaround):

It seems Eclipse is intolerant (buggy) of certain characters in the file names when using relative pathing, which is probably why @thedrs noted "others won't work with it". Simple "../" (@mark ad me) or "./../" (@thedrs) or "VAR_NAME/"  (@Renardo) work equally. It is the file names that break things.

- Minimally tolerated: [lowercase letters],[one period],[minus sign "-"]
- Minimally disrespected: [upper case letters],[multiple periods],[digits]

Those are just what I figured out, testing in Windows 10 with Eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0), Build id: 20210612-2011; I did not test all characters. In this case @mark was been bitten since his files names have multiple period characters, and also because they have digits, in the file names. Change a file name to "test-bug.jar" and see it work, make a file "test1-bug.jar" and see it fail. Shame on @mark for keeping identifying version numbers in his jar names. And shame on Eclipse for now supporting a pattern and/or folder as well as individual jar names.

Fortunately I had a wider mix of characters in my file names, with some versioned and some not, and after half a day of insisting it must be a bug noticed the pattern.

*Update: I got the latest version of Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers, Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0), Build id: 20231201-2043 and he bugs persist.*